# understand how postman deals with request headers

Tags: python-requests, postman

I'm using postman to make a GET request.

let's say my url is: `https://mywebsite.com/api/records/count` that is responding with a json array with the last date and the corresponding count of records:

```
{"date": "2022-11-11", "value": 123}
```

I find out that the first request is giving me a random number, then the following ones are giving me a fixed number with is the correct one (123). How is it possible? when I try to replicate this with Python, I always get random numbers (never get the 123)
I believe there is something to do with cookies, so I've tried to retrieve cookies and sent them back to the server, but doesn't work:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.get("https://mywebsite.com/")
cookies = sessions.get_cookies()
```

anything else I could try? Postman is getting the right number without any custom headers

Comment: Check the 'Headers' section of the Postman to see if you're passing the 'Cookie' field. If not, then it's not something to do with Cookies.

Comment: thanks @KishanLal it works the same with or without cookies. if it's something to do with it, how would you explain it? what make Postman succeed while python fails? thanks for the help

Comment: I'm wondering the same. If you have control over the server, log the request and compare the request of the postman and python. Make sure you're using the latest version of python-requests module.